# Room database query that gives out a list with exclusions

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to query Room to pull a list of elements `Entry`, but would like to exclude some elements from an `Array<Int>`.

My database:

```
@Entity(tableName = "entries", indices = [Index(value = ["id"], unique = true)])
```

My object class which will populate my list:

```
data class Entry(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
override var id: Int?,
override val authorId: Int)
```

My current query to fetch all these elements:

```
@Query("SELECT * from entries")
fun entryList() : DataSource.Factory<Int, Entry>
```

I have an `Array<Int>` which represent a list of `authorId` that want to exclude from my results.

I could filter the `entryList` afterwards, but I would prefer to make a query so retrieve a smaller list.

Question: Which query should I use to pull an `entryList` that exclude the `authorId` found in my `Array<Int>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE authorId NOT IN (:filterValues)")
```

and pass `Array<Int> filterValues` as parameter.

See if it works